# difference in CPU time for two similar lines

Tags: c++, c, assembly, profiling, cpu-usage

There is a while loop in my program, where `IterZNext`, `IterZ` are pointers to nodes in a list. The nodes in the list are of type struct with a field called "Index".

```
double xx = 20.0;
double yy = 10000.0;
double zz;      
while (IterZNext!=NULL && NextIndex<=NewIndex)
{
    IterZ=IterZNext;
    IterZNext = IterZ->Next;
    if (IterZNext!=NULL)
    {
        zz = xx + yy;
                NextIndex1 = IterZNext->Index; // line (*)
        NextIndex = IterZNext->Index;  // line (**)
        IterZNext->Index;
    }
}
```

When I profiled my program, I found the line (*)

```
NextIndex1 = IterZNext->Index;
```

consumes most of CPU time (2.193s), while the line (**)

```
NextIndex = IterZNext->Index;
```

which is all most the same with the line (*) only uses 0.093s. I used the Intel VTune Amplifier to see the assembly of these two lines, which is as follows:

```
Address Line    Assembly                   CPU Time Instructions Retired
Line (*):
0x1666  561 mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-0x44]   0.015s  50,000,000
0x1669  561 mov ecx, dword ptr [eax+0x8]        
0x166c  561 mov dword ptr [ebp-0x68], ecx   2.178s  1,614,000,000

Line (**):
0x166f  562 mov byte ptr [ebp-0x155], 0x1   0.039s  80,000,000
0x1676  562 mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-0x44]   0.027s  44,000,000
0x1679  562 mov ecx, dword ptr [eax+0x8]        
0x167c  562 mov dword ptr [ebp-0x5c], ecx   0.026s  94,000,000
```

If I change the order of the line (*) and the line (**), then the program changes to

```
double xx = 20.0;
double yy = 10000.0;
double zz;      
while (IterZNext!=NULL && NextIndex<=NewIndex)
{
    IterZ=IterZNext;
    IterZNext = IterZ->Next;
    if (IterZNext!=NULL)
    {
        zz = xx + yy;
                NextIndex = IterZNext->Index;  // line (**)
                NextIndex1 = IterZNext->Index; // line (*)
        IterZNext->Index;
    }
}
```

and the result for assembly changes to

```
Address Line    Assembly    CPU Time    Instructions Retired
Line (**):
0x1666  560 mov byte ptr [ebp-0x155], 0x1   0.044s  84,000,000
0x166d  560 mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-0x44]   0.006s  2,000,000
0x1670  560 mov ecx, dword ptr [eax+0x8]    0.001s  4,000,000
0x1673  560 mov dword ptr [ebp-0x5c], ecx   1.193s  1,536,000,000

Line (*):
0x1676  561 mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-0x44]   0.052s  128,000,000
0x1679  561 mov ecx, dword ptr [eax+0x8]        
0x167c  561 mov dword ptr [ebp-0x68], ecx   0.034s  112,000,000
```

In this case, line (**) uses most of CPU time (1.245s) while line (*) only uses 0.086s.

Could someone tell me:
(1) Why does it take so long to make the first assignment? Notice that the line zz=xx+yy only uses 0.058s. Is this related to the cache misses? since all nodes in the list are dynamically genereated.
(2) Why is there huge difference in CPU time between this two lines?

Thanks!

Comment: On what are you basing your statement about relative CPU time for each source code line - what's the profiler and result output?

Answer (score 6):

All modern CPUs are superscaler & out-of-order - which means that instructions are not actually executed in the order of the assembly, and there isn't really such thing as the current PC - there are many 10s of instructions in flight and executing at once.

Therefore any sampling information a CPU reports is just a rough area the CPU was executing - it was executing the instruction it indicated when the sampling interrupt went off; but it was also executing all the other in-flight ones!

However people have got used to (and expect) profiling tools to tell them *exactly* which individual instruction the CPU is currently running - so when the sampling interrupt triggers the CPU essentially picks one of the many active instructions to be the 'current' one.

Comment: Perhaps if you base the profiling on the actual performance counters of the chip (such as valgrind and oprofile seem to be able to do) you'll at least get 'factual' data... [lot's of it in fact](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/intel-corei7-events.php). So much, that in reality, it is probably useless to base analysis on, if you're not an intel employee :) (_you'd still have to manually combine the raw data on all these inputs, which is hard to do without knowing the exact architecture on the chip_)

Comment: @sehe - Indeed - however it's not so much a lack of information as the fact that there isn't a single PC at any instant in time. If you could get 'true' CPU profiling information on a given cycle it would state which micro-ops of which instructions happen to be in each different CPU unit at that time - far from a single PC ;)

Answer (score 5):

[CPU line caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) is probably the reason. accessing `[ebp-0x5c]` also brings into the cache `[ebp-0x68]`, which then will be fetched much faster (for the second case, vice versa for the first).

Comment: CPU caching will be a part of it; but if it was just this effect then you would expect to see exactly the same times for each ordering; just the other way around - however what we get is {2.19s,0.09s} for A and {1.24s,0.08s} for B.

Comment: @Dave - there's also the memory latency involved, and the bus, and the profiler impact, which all contribute.

Comment: Yes, but again the fundamental issue here is that no modern out-of-order CPU has a single 'current PC' and all data is statistical. Certainly two IPs only a few instructions apart in straight-line code are not really distinguishable.

Comment: @Dave - the fundamental issue is that profiling per assembly line is pointless.

Comment: Yep; that's what I'm saying ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitly due to the cache miss. Then bigger miss then more performance penalty will be introduced by processor. Actually in the modern world CPU performs much faster then memory. If nowadays processor can have clock frequency in about 4GHz, memory still run with frequency ~0.3GHz. It is great performance gap that is still continue to grow. Cache introduction was driven by desire to hide this gap. Without cache using modern processor will spend huge amount of time waiting data from the memory and doing nothing at that time. In addition to the performance gap, each memory access incurrs additional latencies related to posible concurrency on memory bus with other CPUs and DMA devices and times required for memory access request processing and routing on the side of the processor memory management logic (checking of the caches of all levels, virtual-to-physical address translation that can involve TLB miss with additional access to memory, request pushing to the memory bus etc.)and memory controller(request routing from the CPU-controller to the controller memory bus, possible waiting for memory bank refresh cycle complition etc.). So, to summarize, raw access to the memory have really big cost in comparision to the L1 cache hit or register access. The difference in cost comparable to the difference in cost to access data in memory and in secondary storage (HDD).

Furthermore, the cost of memory access will grow with moving from the processor to the memory. L2 access will provide bigger penalty then L1 or CPU registers access, L3 access will provide penalty bigger then L2 access and, finally, memory access will provide penalty bigger then memory access. For example, you can compare cost of data access on different levels of memory hierarchy in the next table (captured from http://www.anandtech.com/show/4955/the-bulldozer-review-amd-fx8150-tested/6)

Cache/Memory Latency Comparison

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|                                |L1| L2| L3| Main Memory |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|AMD FX-8150 (3.6GHz)            | 4| 21| 65| 195         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|AMD Phenom II X4 975 BE (3.6GHz)| 3| 15| 59| 182         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|AMD Phenom II X6 1100T (3.3GHz) | 3| 14| 55| 157         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|Intel Core i5 2500K (3.3GHz)    | 4| 11| 25| 148         |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

In regard to your particular case:

```
0x1669  561 mov ecx, dword ptr [eax+0x8]        
0x166c  561 mov dword ptr [ebp-0x68], ecx   2.178s  1,614,000,000


0x1670  560 mov ecx, dword ptr [eax+0x8]    0.001s  4,000,000 /* confusing and looks like wrong report for me*/ 
0x1673  560 mov dword ptr [ebp-0x5c], ecx   1.193s  1,536,000,000
```

You have penalty on dereferencing of the Index value in the code line.

```
mov ecx, dword ptr [eax+0x8]
```

Note that it is first access to the data in each subsequent node of you list, up to this moment you manipulate only by node address, but the data of that address and due to this haven't memory access. 
You stated, that you use dynamical list, and this is bad from cache hit rate point of vies. In addition, I suppose that you have big enough list that mean that you will have cache fluded by the previously accessed data (list nodes accessed on previous iterations)and almost always will have cache miss or cache hit only on L3 cache during the accessing Index on each new iteration.  But note, that during first access to the Index on each involving cache miss on each new iteration data returned from the memory will be stored in the L1 cache. And when you access Index on the second time during the same cycle iteration, you will have low cost L1 cache hit!

So I hope I provide you detailed answer on both your questions.

In regard to the correctness of the VTune report correctness. I want to advocate Intel VTune developers. Of course, modern processors are very complex devices with number of ILP improving technologies on the board including pipelining, superscalaring, Out-Of-Order execution, branch prediction etc, and of cource this make detailed instruction level performance analysis harder and more precious. But such tools like VTune is developed with that processor features in the mind, and I belive that they are not so stupied to develop and provide the tool or feature that haven't any sence. Furthermore it looks like the developers from the Intel like no another have access to the full understanding of the all processor features details and as no another can take this details into account during profiler designing and development.